# using xlwt writing data into the excel but in this code not properly inserting into the column

Tags: python, excel

```
import xlwt
wbk = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = wbk.add_sheet('python')
row = 0
f = open('newfile.txt')
for line in f:
L = line.strip().split()
for i,c in enumerate(L):
    sheet.write(row,i,c)
    row += 1
    wbk.save('examp1.xls')
```

in this code it is inserted into columns but each column gets iterating not in the same row

Comment: What is your question? Can you please show example of what is in `newfile.txt` and what you are getting? and what you expected?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that python is a language in which code blocks are defined by the indentation level. If you want to put each field from a CSV into a separate column in a spreadsheet, the second loop should be an inner loop of the first. Unless I am very much mistaken you don't want to save the file after every operation. That would cause a massive slow down.

```
import xlwt
wbk = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = wbk.add_sheet('python')
row = 0
f = open('newfile.txt')
for line in f:
   L = line.strip().split()
   for i,c in enumerate(L):
       sheet.write(row,i,c)
       row += 1

wbk.save('examp1.xls')
```